# Joomla 3.2 Module specific notice "echo" in frontend

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla, echo

I'm trying to get access to some information which are predefined in the backend of joomla

id  asset_id title  note active
90  61  Testtitle   testnote 1

I've tried the same code with getInt ItemeId and it worked for another table but not for the suppose so i tried getInt id

This is some code im trying to get to work but the echo $note isnt working

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;


$menuitemid = JRequest::getInt('id');
$db     =& JFactory::getDBO();  
$query = "SELECT note FROM #__modules WHERE published = 1 and id = '".$menuitemid."' ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$note = $db->loadResult();

?>


<div title="**<?php echo $note ?>**" class="custom<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx ?>" <?php if ($params->get('backgroundimage')) : ?> style="background-image:url(<?php echo $params->get('backgroundimage');?>)"<?php endif;?> >
    <?php echo $module->content;?>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

**As with the suggestion provided ive edited my code to this (this also wont work actually):**

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$menuitemid = $jinput->get('id', null, 'INT');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();     
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('note')
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__modules'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('published') . ' = '. (int)1 . 
      ' AND' . $db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $db->quote($menuitemid));

$db->setQuery($query);     
$note = $db->loadResult();
?>


<div title="<?php echo $note ?>" class="custom<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx ?>" <?php if ($params->get('backgroundimage')) : ?> style="background-image:url(<?php echo $params->get('backgroundimage');?>)"<?php endif;?> >
    <?php echo $module->content;?>
</div>
```

And finally with some own improvements i got this functioning code:
To catch the specific module id ive changed the AND SELECTOION id  to $module->id

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$menuitemid = $jinput->get('id', null, 'INT');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();     
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('note')
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__modules'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('published') . ' = '. (int)1 . 
      ' AND' . $db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $module->id);

$db->setQuery($query);     
$note = $db->loadResult();
echo $note;
```

Comment: `JRequest` is deprecated. You should be using `JInput`. Be sure to read the Joomla documentation

Comment: its a snippet of a code which was used to get access to information in menu table of mysql. $menuitemid should get the id of the actual module in which the code appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lets go through this bit by bit. As mentioned in my comment, `JRequest` is deprecated, so you will need to use the following:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$menuitemid = $jinput->get('id', null, 'INT');
```

You're database query using using old coding standards and does not using any escaping methods. The following, which is also provided on the Joomla Documentation is what you should be using:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();     
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('note')
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__modules'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('published') . ' = '. (int)1 . 
      ' AND' . $db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $db->quote($menuitemid));

$db->setQuery($query);     
$note = $db->loadResult();

echo $note;
```

In the query above, you will see I have use `(int)1` which means that the value will always be an integer. I have also used `quoteName()` for fields and `quote()` for the value which are used to escape.

This will output the `note` that you have assigned to the module. I have tested this and it works perfectly for me.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but it wont work for me at the moment.
First when i tried usin JInput the error call to a non member function appeared every time, this time the code is appropriate but it wont show the information needed when echoing. Do we need the menuitemid for this?
Ive checked the database but the information are saved correctly and are active.

Comment: echo $menuitemid gave also no integer value

Comment: The best thing to do would be to check the `note` column your database table. You are checking for `published = 1` and `id = $menuitemid`. If you do `var_dump($menuitemid)`, this should output the ID. I can guarantee this works as I added it to the top of the login module. I then got `24` as the ID and it displayed the note text for me.

Comment: `var_dump($note)` won't work until the ID is correct, but How can you be getting `null`? Where are you adding this code to? i added the code to `modules\mod_custom\tmpl\default.php` and it's fine

Comment: me too, thats the whole default.php from /modules/mod_custom/tmpl/

edit:http://pastebin.com/TAk2u6bx

Comment: Hmm ok the code looks fine. Silly question but have you published the module? If so, have you published the correct one?

Comment: The code should appear on every custom_html module. with this code at my website there's at every custom_html module a text bit with "NULL" so it is affecting the active module.
The modules are published, as seen on my website the NULL output is given at every of this modules

edit: heres a screenshot of phpmyadmin
http://eren-web-design-development.tk/modules/mod_custom/tmpl/Untitled1.png

Comment: and for the question if its published http://eren-web-design-development.tk/modules/mod_custom/tmpl/Untitled2.png

Comment: Can you please try upgrading to Joomla 3.3, as there also shouldn't be any reason for you to be on 3.2

Comment: is there any steps i should do before i upgrade except the backup? is there a possibility that information which aren't set as a override will be overwritten by upgrade?

Comment: No, it should be a smooth upgrade. Taking a backup of the site and database is the only thing you should do

Comment: Ok i´ll try that in a while, copying data & sql at the moment, i'll report if above code is working under 3.3

Comment: No difference, it only works with my provided code.
Actual Version 3.3.1

Comment: Ahh I see, I was only testing this with 1 instance of a custom module, I didn't try 2 instances of it. Glad it working for you. And btw, the latest version of Joomla is 3.3.3 ;)